# Apply changes only to the clicked item among several items with same method name

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, events

I have several divs that show various details. i have intended to take the details from the backend and bind them to my html part. To the time being i have hardcoded the details. This is my html part

```
<div className="trait_box polaroid" onClick={this.trait_select}>
  <div className="main_trait_card" style={{transform: this.state.rotated ? 'rotateY(180deg)' : 'none' }}>
    <div className="front_card_rotate">
      <div className="trait_description_div">
        <span className="trait_description">Honesty</span>
      </div>
      <div className="trait_img_div">
        <img src={Honesty} className="trait_img"/>
      </div>
      <div className="block__body">
          <img src={Add} className="trait_add"/>
            <p className="trait_text">Honesty refers to a facet of moral character and connotes positive and virtuous attributes such as integrity, truthfulness,straightforwardness etc.. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div className="back_card_rotate front_card_rotate">
          <span>Wolverine</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the div that will repeat according to how many items there in the backend.

I'm rotating these divs onClick like this

```
constructor() {
        super();
          this.state = {rotated: false};
          this.trait_select = this.trait_select.bind(this);
}
trait_select = (e) => {
          this.setState({rotated: !this.state.rotated});
}
```

My problem is as the same css classes are repeating, when there are more than 1 items, everytime will rotate when i click on a item. Because every item has the same css classes. How can i differentiate the item i click from the other items?

Answer (score 1):

I think each trait_box should be a component and manage your own state:

```
 class TraitBox extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { rotate: false }        
   }
   trait_select = (e) => {...}
   render() {
      return ( <div className="trait_box..." ></div> )
   }
 }

 // and then you can import/use that component in a container
 class ContainerApp extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <TraitBox />
       <TraitBox />
       <TraitBox />
     )
   }
 }
```

Now, each TraitBox can manage your own state and styles

Btw, you don't need this:

```
 this.trait_select = this.trait_select.bind(this);
```

if trait_select is a arrow function( AF should bind "this" automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the boolean with an array and use `e.target.name` to identify the clicked trait:

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = { rotated_traits: [] };
  this.trait_select = this.trait_select.bind(this);
}

trait_select = (e) => {
  const rotated_traits = this.state.rotated_traits

  rotated_traits[e.target.name] = !this.state.rotated_traits[e.target.name]

  this.setState({ rotated_traits });
}
```

And

```html
<div className="trait_box polaroid" name={trait.id} onClick={this.trait_select}>
  <div className="main_trait_card" style={{transform: this.state.rotated_traits[trait.id] ? 'rotateY(180deg)' : 'none' }}>
    ..
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't have a `trait.id`, you can use the `index`:

```
traits.map((trait, index) =>
  ...
)
```